# Changing storyboard constraints for keyboard animation bounce

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, keyboard, constraints

I'm having a problem with changing constraints when the keyboard is shown. 
I'm currently building a login screen where I have set up constraints to center a stackview with 2 textfields and a button horizontally and vertically in the frame. The logo (imageview) is above the stackview and has seperate constraints.

When the keyboard appears, I want to animate the constraints to move the stackview and logo up a bit so the keyboard doesn't cover anything.

The keyboard also has a "next" button and a "go" button on the fields.

**The problem** I'm having now is that everytime I press "next" or clear the textfield, the constraints change again and thus the stackview and logo "bounce", which is a bit annoying. Also, I know a lot of people will probably sugest to use a scrollview, but that's not really an option here.
I also have buttons at the bottom to create an account so I can't really change the entire frame height either.

I'm guessing that because it's calling "textField.resignFirstResponder()", the "keyboardWillHide" notification is called and thus it starts animating.

I've searched everywhere on the internet and tried a lot of things to solve it, but I'm really out of ideas and motivation right now, so I hope someone has an idea of what I might be doing wrong here. 
Thanks in advance!

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var emailField: SkyFloatingLabelTextFieldWithIcon!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: SkyFloatingLabelTextFieldWithIcon!
@IBOutlet weak var signInBtn: TransitionSubmitButton!
@IBOutlet weak var contentCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var logoTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var equalWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupKeyboardButtons()
    addObservers()

    // using extension to hide keyboard when tapped around
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}

func addObservers(){

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(goToDifferentView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LoginPressed"), object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification){

    // calling layoutIfNeeded because otherwise text in textfield bounces when animating for some reason
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.contentCenterConstraint.constant = -50
    self.equalWidthConstraint.constant = -30
    self.logoTopConstraint.constant = -10
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification){


    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.contentCenterConstraint.constant = 0
    self.equalWidthConstraint.constant = 0
    self.logoTopConstraint.constant = 10
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

private func setupKeyboardButtons(){
    // textfield delegates instellen, dit dient om keyboard actions te kunnen doen
    self.emailField.delegate = self
    self.emailField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
    self.passwordField.delegate = self
    self.passwordField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    switch(textField) {
    case self.emailField:
        self.passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
        break
    case self.passwordField:

        signInBtn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
        break
    default:
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        break
    }
    return true
}

// remove observers
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to just add a boolean to check if the keyboard is "active" or not, it might not be the cleanest solution, but it fixed the problem, hope this helps in case anyone else runs into this.